# GCS loading all data from CSV into one column

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using an API to get some data, from which I extract 2 columns to load into a GCS bucket :

```
 response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
 response.encoding = "UTF-8"

 reader = csv.reader(response.text.splitlines(), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    
tabResult = []

for r in reader:
     try:
         tabResult.append(f"{r[0]};{r[6]}")
     except Exception:
         print(r)

 stringResult = "\n".join(tabResult)

 blob = bucket.blob("users.csv")
 blob.upload_from_string(stringResult)
```

I then want to import this data into a BigQuery table, but the problem is that GCS considers there is only 1 column in my csv file, so the data inside looks like this :

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1;2022-01-01 |
| 2;2022-01-02 |

Instead of looking like this :

| ID | Registration_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 |

So when I try to upload the data into BigQuery, I get this error :

`400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:21 contains only 1 columns.`

How can I fix it ? Before using the `upload_from_string` method I used `upload_from_file`, which worked very well, but we decided not to store files on our server because of performance concerns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't transform the file, simply use a custom `field_delimiter`!!

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True, 
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    field_delimiter=";"
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.json"
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the best way of doing it ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [hidden in the doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect?hl=en)

```
Schema auto-detection for CSV data
CSV delimiter
BigQuery detects the following delimiters:

comma ( , )
pipe ( | )
tab ( \t )
```

I simply had to replace

```
    for r in reader:
        try:
            tabResult.append(f"{r[0]};{r[6]}")
```

with

```
    for r in reader:
        try:
            tabResult.append(f"{r[0]},{r[6]}")
```